# .htaccess rule condition exclution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this rule to send any URL to the index, then analyze it and show the correct content with any URL I want.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

I need to exclude this rule if the url goes to `/admin` or to `/js` and `/css`, but I don't know how to condition out this rule because it has no variable I can check - actually I do not even fully understand how this rule works because I don't see it transfer the .* in any variable....

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|admin|js|css)
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

If you want, you can make it as 2 separate conditions, but there is no real need for this (it should be faster with only 1 condition):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|js|css)/
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the additional `RewriteCond` added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|css|js)
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

You aren't transferring the `.*`, but rather directly rewriting everything to `index.php`.  You may also want to append the existing querystring with `[QSA]`

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php  [L,QSA]
```